# count rectangles in n*n chessboard

Tags: c++

Task:calculate total 
I used the approach given here [count rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178693/analysis-of-how-many-squares-and-rectangles-are-are-there-on-a-chess-board)

That is ((n+1)c2)^2

The Logic seems to be correct since it is passing all small test cases
Is it some truncation during result calculation if it is then how i can i avoid that

But failing at

Input:
9384

Its Correct output is:
1938754650726740

And Your Code's output is:
1939030144736400

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define int unsigned long long 
int32_t main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        n=n+1;
        int t = ((n*(n-1))>>1);
        t=t*t;
        cout<<t<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define int unsigned long long` OMG

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. By simply taking the square root of 1938754650726740 we can see that the answer is not a square number. There must be something wrong with either the question or the answer or your formula, which does not feel like something for Stack Overflow.

Comment: A few issues here: the define is crazy; t could bust (overflow)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your result and the solution is equal to the number of squares:

```
n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
```

Your result corresponds to the number of rectangles, including the squares.

I guess that what is expected is the number of rectangles which are not squares.

Besides, absolutely avoid

```
#define int unsigned long long
```

I don't have time to search and list all the reasons not to do that. One is enough for me: the code becomes unreadable.